# Proof of Riemann Rearrangement Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, alternative-proof, conditional-convergence

I'm reading the proof of Riemann Rearrangement Theorem in T. Tao's Analysis 1 textbook which can be found here 
[Rearrangement Thm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622584/rearrangement-thm)
(the parts missing from the textbook, left as exercises for the reader, are completed by the user asking the question)
but I don't understand the last line of the proof where the user says 
"If $u_i <l_i$ then for all $u_i \leq k\leq l_i$ we therefore have...";
to affirm that $S_k \to L$ shouldn't one prove that it is always $S_{l_i}\leq S_{k}\leq S_{u_i}$ to be able to invoke the Squeeze Theorem?
I don't understand how that proof accomplishes this.

Could someone explain this part of that proof or show me another way to finish the proof?

Best regards,

lorenzo.

Comment: @Ross Millikan :thanks for your reply; when you say "if $u_i <l_i $..." do you mean "if $u_i <l_i \forall i\in\mathbb{N}$" ? Else I don't know how you can apply the Squeeze Theorem later. Also, from what you say I assume that either $u_i <l_i$ or $l_i <u_i \forall i\in\mathbb{N}$; is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paragraph just above what your are asking about completes the proof.  The one you are asking about is not correct.  The $u$s are the next to last in a run of negative terms we are adding, so they are the last partial sum that is greater than $L$ for a while.  We add one more negative term and drop below $L$, so we start adding positive terms. Similarly, the $\ell$s are the next to last in a run of positive terms, so they are the last partial sum that is less than $L$ for a while.  We add one more positive term and rise above $L$, so we start adding negative terms.

If $u_i \lt \ell_i$, $S_{u_i+1}$ is a local minimum, so for all $k$ such that $u_i+1 \le k \le \ell_i$ we would have $S_{u_i+1} \le S_k \le S_{\ell_i}\lt L \lt S_{u_i}$  Now since $|S_{u_i}-S_{u_i+1}|\to 0$ because it is one term and the terms are converging to zero we get the squeeze we want.  The case of $\ell_i \lt u_i$ is similar.

Comment: The $u$s and $\ell$s have to alternate, so that will be true.  We just don't know which one we start with.

Comment: can you prove that the $u$s and the $l$s have to alternate rigorously? I've tried to do this by induction by I haven't gotten anywhere so far. After this I'll mark your answer as the accepted one. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, it is in the definition of my first paragraph.  After a $u$ you add one more negative term and the sum drops below $L$.  You now add positive terms until you get above $L$.  The next $\ell$ is the next to last of those positive terms, and there can't be a $u$ there because you haven't been above $L$ yet.  Then after the next positive after the $\ell$ you are above $L$ and start adding negative terms.  You can't have another $\ell$ until after you finish with the negative terms, so the next one is a $u$